# Drop down menu hyperlinks click event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

Please take a look on my code [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/iisgdzrv), I have a multi level menu. Problem is that the hyperlinks are only working on child list items e.g. Brands has 5 child items (Samsung, Nokia, Apple, Sony, LG) and hyperlinks are working fine on them, but on parent items (Home, Phones, Tablets, News) etc hyperlinks are not working. 
I used code of [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/orman-clarks-vertical-navigation-menu-the-css3-version--webdesign-5944).
Please help me because my javascript is not good.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the preventDefault inside the click handler all hrefs are ignored. I would recommend to add the href only on the menu items which actually need them and add this to your click handler, to follow the links:

```
menu_a.click(function (e) {

          if( $(this).attr('href') ){
           location.href =  $(this).attr('href');
            return;
          }
```

here you can find your working example:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/v5bujr6c

Comment: yes, I have tried that. But then drop down list items e.g on Brand doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean you don't get linked to other websites? That's my best guess. The only thing you need to do is change the href of the element. For example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, I think I didn't explain well. These are just example links, so people can see if hyperlink click event triggered or not. If you see in you code and click on Home, click even doesn't trigger and if you click on any sub items of Brand e.g. 'Apple' the hyperlink click even trigger fine.